# Naming convention / Multi platform implementation

Tags: c++, cmake, naming-conventions

I have the following folder structure

```
include
  -- GPIO.h (1)

src
  desktop
    -- GPIO.cpp (2)
  raspi
    -- GPIO.cpp (3)
--GPIO.cpp (4)
```

1 - declaration (a few simple classes)

2 - impl. GPIO simulation for desktop (host of xcompiler)

3 - impl. bcm2835_xxx functions talking to Raspi

4 - impl. functions universal for both platforms

Good/Bad? Tips?

(And Yes - I know: Usually one class per file is better but my GPIO.h has one main class and a few helper / enum classes - rather simple...)

I'm unsure about splitting the platform specific parts into subfolders...

The idea behind this structure is that I don't want precompiler-checks in my cpp's - cmake controls which source-part is compiled/included for each platform.

Comment: As CMake itself has no special treatment of filenames for `.c` files, naming of such files is up to developer.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Yes, I know, Thanks. My solution via cmake already works.